# how would i go about making a button that once clicked will give you a response from a list of words

Tags: javascript, html

how would i go about making a button that once clicked will give you a response from a list of words and will prevent from showing the same response on the list again. im having trouble thinking of ways and i just need an idea on how to do it i hope this is not a stupid question but it probably is.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Tell what your code like or what have you thought?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this solution is good or not, You should create a separate class contains `display: none` and insert it into your attributes list. And add event listen to your button when clicking toggle that class you are created with display none, so it's will show and hide your list when you click.

Comment: That would mean all responses are initially visible or invisible, and does not solve the problem of how to keep track of the responses that have already been displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
const textField = document.getElementById('spnData');

const responses = [
  { response: "Hello", shown: false },
  { response: "World", shown: false },
  { response: "How", shown: false },
  { response: "Are", shown: false },
  { response: "You", shown: false },
  { response: "Today", shown: false },
];

const getRandomUnseenResponse = () => {
  const unseenItems = responses.filter((item) => item.shown === false);
  if (!unseenItems || unseenItems.length === 0) return null;
  return unseenItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * unseenItems.length)];
};

document.getElementById('btnResponse').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const selectedResponse = getRandomUnseenResponse();
  if (!selectedResponse || selectedResponse.length === 0) {
    spnData.innerHTML = "You've seen everything!";
  } else {
    spnData.innerHTML = selectedResponse.response;
    responses.filter((item) => item.response === selectedResponse.response)[0].shown = true;
  }
});
```

In essence, we are keeping track of the items that have been displayed using an extra property called `shown` in the array of responses. We set the value of the `shown` property to `true` once the item has been displayed and we filter out the items that have already been shown when we select a random response.

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vdso6am8/

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion:

```
var words=["a", "b", "c"];
var used = [];
var num = 0;
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}
function getWord(){
  if(num >= words.length){
// no word can use
  }
  let temp = words[getRndInterget(0, words.length)];
  if(used.includes(temp)){
      return getWord();
  }
  used.push(temp);
  num += 1;
  return temp;
}
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let re = getWord();
  //use of re
});
```

Comment: I would recommend making use of newer JS language features such as `let` and `const` when creating variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just shuffle the array of words and use them all in turn. When you reach the end you can shuffle again or just go round the same array again.

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <input id="txt" type="text">
        <button id="but">Next</button>
    </body>
    <script>

        function shuffled(array) {
            const result = [...array];
            let m = result.length;

            while (m) {
                const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

                const t = result[m];
                result[m] = result[i];
                result[i] = t;
            }

            return result;
        }
        
        const shuffledWords = shuffled(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']);
        console.log(shuffledWords)

        let index = 0;
        document.getElementById('but').addEventListener('click', () => {
            
            document.getElementById('txt').value = shuffledWords[index++];
            if (index === shuffledWords.length) index = 0;            
        });

    </script>
</html>
```